# Como usar sockets en las rutas de un proyecto con nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, socket.io

muy buenas comunidad. Tengo una duda. Resulta que quiero que emitir un socket cada vez que se le hace una consulta a una ruta en nodejs con express, es posible hacer esto? y como se puede hacer? Quiero saber esto ya que no he encontrado mucha información al respecto y soy nuevo con sockets

Comment: ¿qué es _emitir un socket_?

Comment: O sea, me refiero a emitir datos a través de un socket